# PHP Race condition for Raffles

Tags: php

I need to create a Raffle system where users can enter the number of tickets they want to buy and pay with credit cards to participate in a raffle. A raffle has a limited number of tickets let's say 1000. Anyone can enter any number of tickets he wants to buy, of course the number should be less or equal to 1000. There is no login in the system so I'm seeing this following as a race condition:

One user enters 998 tickets to buy and another one enters 5 tickets, if both users click on submit on the same time and I process both requests is this going to be a race condition? If yes, has anyone came across a similar case and is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many programmers will approach this by checking the database for sufficient tickets and if found then updating the ticket sales. This leaves a window between the read and write parts of the operation where the race condition exists.

```
User A reads (reads 1000 tickets)
    User B reads (reads 1000 tickets)
User A writes(reduces tickets left by 998, writes 2)
    User B writes (reduces tickets left by 5, writes 995)
```

We're left with 1003 tickets 'sold', and a remaining balance of 995 tickets to sell. This is clearly not acceptable.

What's required is an atomic test-and-set operation (atomic, because it's indivisible)

Fortunately, databases treat single queries as atomic, and also provide a mechanism for the test-and-set requirement

Consider the query

```
UPDATE `raffles` set `ticketsLeft` = `ticketsLeft`- 995 WHERE `raffleID` = 'someId' and `ticketsLeft` >= 995
```

This will test for sufficient tickets and deduct the tickets sold all as part of one query. There's no window in which a race can exist.

But, how does the program know that the update succeeded?

The database handles that too. The program asks the database for the number of **rows affected** by the UPDATE query. If the update succeeds one row is affected. If it fails (no `raffleId` or insufficient tickets) no rows are affected.

Thus, the program executes its query, and checks the rows affected. If the answer is 1 the ticket sale succeeded. If the answer is zero, the ticket sale failed. The program handles these two possibilities and carries on.<sup>*</sup>

For PHP there are two interfaces to MySQL: see [mysqli::affected_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php), or [PDOStatement::rowcount()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) for the details.

Other databases have similar constructions.

<sup>*</sup> Data integrity is assured here by applying a UNIQUE index to the `raffleId` column, guaranteeing there will only be one matching raffle, or none.

Comment: hmm, your approach is interesting and frankly it solves the issue even though I have to test it by running two scripts at the same time and I will get back with the result on this here, however, your query that does the check and update on the same time will need in prior another SELECT query to get the total left tickets 'ticketsLeft' from any previous operation before doing that deduction. Am I right? If yes, can the select and update be done in one query to keep no window in which this race can exist? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to SELECT the rows to get remaining tickets to display to the customer then you can. That's a separate operation, and there's a chance that another customer will buy them first. The actual update doesn't require a prior SELECT because it's governed by its own WHERE clause. If there are enough tickets the update succeeds and returns one row affected. If there aren't, the UPDATE fails and return zero rows affected....more

Comment: ...You can use [SELECT...FOR UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html), but that locks the rows for some indeterminate time, and you have to ensure that you guarantee to release those rows, no matter what happens.

Comment: Perfect thanks for sharing this approach.